# [Android]Registering fingerprints in application

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

Want to design an app that registers the user with password field as fingerprint, got a [google sample code from github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog), It asks the user to add the fingerprint in ***Settings*** as many as we want and it authenticates the user from the existing fingerprints by calling the authenticate() of the FingerprintManager

How could I register a new fingerprint from app and get it stored in sqlite or in cloud?

Is there any external Bluetooth Biometric sensor and SDK support for android?

Comment: AFAIK, none of what you want is possible. The user can only register fingerprints through Settings (not through your app), and you cannot obtain fingerprint data to upload anywhere.

Comment: Is it possible saving the username with the fingerprint in Settings

Comment: I do not know what you mean by that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty confident that the Fingerprint APIs specifically don't allow the developer to access the actuall fingerprint data, and instead just respond with a "Pass/Fail".

If the data was released, it could be reverse engineered and would be a privacy concern.

Comment: Is there any external Bluetooth Biometric sensor and SDK support for android?

Comment: That is a different question ;-). I have no idea if there is a 3rd party BLE supported fingerprint device (probably - but SO is for software)